# Multiprocessing pool map_async for one function then block before the next (python 3)

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, multiprocessing

please be warned that this demonstration code generates a few GB data.

I have been using versions of the code below for multiprocessing for some time. It works well when the run time of each process in the pool is similar but if one process takes much longer I end up with many blocked processes waiting on the one, so I'm trying to make it run asynchronously - just for one function at a time.

For example, if I have 70 cores and need to run a function 2000 times I want that to run asynchronously then wait for the last process before calling the next function. Currently it just submits processes in batches of how ever many cores I give it and each batch has to wait for the longest process.

As you can see I've tried using map_async but this is clearly the wrong syntax. Can anyone help me out?

```
import os
p='PATH/test/'

def f1(tup):
    x,y=tup
    to_write = x*(y**5)
    with open(p+x+str(y)+'.txt','w') as fout:
        fout.write(to_write)

def f2(tup):
    x,y=tup
    print (os.path.exists(p+x+str(y)+'.txt'))

def call_func(f,nos,threads,call):
    print (call)
    for i in range(0, len(nos), threads):
        print (i)
        chunk = nos[i:i + threads]
        tmp = [('args', no) for no in chunk]
        pool.map(f, tmp)
        #pool.map_async(f, tmp)

nos=[i for i in range(55)]
threads=8
if __name__ == '__main__':
with Pool(processes=threads) as pool:
    call_func(f1,nos,threads,'f1')
    call_func(f2,nos,threads,'f2')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` will only return and `map_async` will only call the callback after all tasks of the current chunk are done.

So you can only either give all tasks to `map`/`map_async` at once or use `apply_async` (initially called `threads` times) where the `callback` calls `apply_async`for the next task.

If the actual return values of the call don't matter (or at least their order doesn't), `imap_unordered` may be another efficient solution when giving it all tasks at once (or an iterator/generator producing the tasks on demand)

Comment: All I had to do was remove the 'chunk' line and it does what I want! Not sure why I ever thought I needed that, must have seen it somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: @LiamMcIntyre If you think my answer is right, you can click the checkmark to the left to accept the answer.